# How to update the remote repo (which has a bad commit) to be in line with local (healthy) repo?

Tags: git

I have a remote branch `origin/master` that has a "bad" commit on it `15.0.25`.

To get around this, I initially reset my local branch to the commit before the bad commit `15.0.24` and then made another commit so that my local branch diverged from the remote.

I now want to update my remote so that it is in line with my local repository (commit `15.0.29`). What would be the safest way to do this?

The bug at `15.0.25` was very painful to debug and I am still not sure what caused it. I am worried about integrating this bug again into my healthy local repository. Ideally, I would like to keep the `15.0.25` commit existing for future reference so I can see what changes caused the issue, I just do not want my remote `origin/master` branch to point to it.

[image]